# Writing a macro in SAS to create a table

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Very new to SAS Programming. Want to start with something simple - writing a macro that run an append query. This is all I have managed to figure out. Where am I going wrong?

```
%MACRO APPENDTEST;
    PROC SQL;
        CREATE TABLE WORK.APPENDTEST AS
        SELECT *
        FROM WORK.MONTHLY_SALES_SUMMARY
    QUIT;
%MEND APPENDTEST;
```

Comment: What does this macro do and how does it differ from your expected outcome? Please provide additional details to prevent this question from being closed as too broad.

Comment: Just want to run a proc sql statement, nothing else. Just want to start learning, so thought I would start with something simple. When I run the code, I don't get any errors but I don't see a new table called AppendTest created either.

Comment: Why are you writing this in a macro?  Get rid of the macro part of things, and just run the code from `proc sql` to `quit`.  Most of SAS programming will be done without macros - it's not like [tag:c] where you need a function wrapper or whatnot.

Comment: I'm also removing the Enterprise Guide from your tags; nothing special about this in EG versus any other way of running SAS.  That should only really be used if you're talking about an EG-specific feature.

Comment: @Joe - This was just the start. I was actually planning to put this in a loop with different date variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a macro but have executed it. This functionality, similar to a function in other languages, allows a macro to compile and execute and different times.

Adding in the following line will call the macro.

```
%appendtest;
```

Comment: I have edited the question cause I'm stuck again...Help please. Getting a bunch of errors. The first one is - A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required.

Comment: Your question is different enough that you should post a new question.